# emacs: Can I set compilation-error-regexp-alist in a mode hook fn?

Tags: emacs, jslint

I am trying to set the `compilation-error-regexp-alist` in a function that I add as a mode hook.

```
(defun cheeso-javascript-mode-fn ()
  (turn-on-font-lock)

   ...bunch of other stuff

  ;; for JSLINT
  (make-local-variable 'compilation-error-regexp-alist)
  (setq compilation-error-regexp-alist
        '(
 ("^[ \t]*\\([A-Za-z.0-9_: \\-]+\\)(\\([0-9]+\\)[,]\\( *[0-9]+\\))\\( Microsoft JScript runtime error\\| JSLINT\\): \\(.+\\)$" 1 2 3)
 ))

  ;;(make-local-variable 'compile-command)
  (setq compile-command
       (let ((file (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)))
         (concat "%windir%\\system32\\cscript.exe \\cheeso\\bin\\jslint.js "  file)))

)

(add-hook 'javascript-mode-hook 'cheeso-javascript-mode-fn)
```

The mode hook runs.  The various things I Set in the mode hook work.  The `compile-command` gets set.  But for some reason, the `compilation-error-regexp-alist` value doesn't take effect.

If I later do a `M-x describe-variable` on `compilation-error-regexp-alist`, it shows me the value I think it should have.  But .. the errors in the compilation buffer don't get highlighted, and `M-x next-error` does not work.

[image]

If I add the error regexp value to the `compilation-error-regexp-alist` via `setq-default`, like this:

```
(setq-default compilation-error-regexp-alist
  '(
     ... jslint regexp here ...
     ... many other regexp's here...
   ))
```

...then it works.  The errors in the compilation buffer get properly highlighted and `M-x next-error` functions as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the `compile` command *inherits* the local value you've set for `compilation-error-regexp-alist`.  The solution would be to customize a hook for the `*compilation*` buffer itself, see [compilation-mode-hook](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompilationMode) and compilation-start-hook.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post on the [mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2011-09/msg00190.html). Apparently `compilation-error-regexp-alist` isn't buffer local so there is not need to have a mode hook.

The mailing list suggests:

- Putting the rules for less-used languages at the beginning of the list.
- Dynamically binding `compilation-error-regexp-alist` in a new function that calls `compile.el` functions itself.